# Can L2CapChannel from IOBluetooth framework in MacOS commentate with L2capChannel in Core Bluetooth framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, l2cap

I am trying to communicate between Mac OS and iOS for sending data back and forth.In Mac OS IOBluetooth framework provides L2cap channel but when I open it and use iOS Core Bluetooth L2CAP it doesnt connect to the channel.How do I make them work as l2capchannel should be same irrespective of the framework.Any ideas or suggestions

Comment: You can communicate between iOS and macOS with L2Cap.  My [demo app](https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo) has both iOS and Mac apps.

Comment: can iOS device connect to IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel from Mac.

Comment: You use Core Bluetooth on both sides; it is available on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks Paulw.I could get them working with Core Bluetooth however the Mac OS app IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel  works with windows as well but I couldn't get the same IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel to work with iOS.Core bluetooth won't work with windows and then I will have to write a separate app for windows and iPhone .Any suggestions

Comment: I have never tried with IOBluetooth, but that framework is for legacy Bluetooth, not BLE. iOS apps only have access to BLE via Core Bluetooth so I don't think you will be able to communicate with an IOBluetooth channel from iOS.

Comment: i think your problem is that your iOS app simply can't discover the Mac unless it is advertising a BLE service, which means core Bluetooth. Did you advertise the IOBluetooth PSM via Core Bluetooth and try and connect to it?

Comment: Thasts correct @Paulw11. I advertise PSM with IOBluetooth with this method  if(sppServiceRecord?.getL2CAPPSM(&psm) != kIOReturnSuccess) and open l2capchannel with selectedDevice?.openL2CAPChannelSync(&l2capChannel, withPSM: psm, delegate: l2chanDelegate)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205549/discussion-between-paulw11-and-md12).